# ClientId not getting captured

Tags: google-analytics

We have three custom dimensions defined in Google Analytics:

- ClientId (dimension1): Session-scoped
- SessionId (dimension2): Session-scoped
- Hit Timestamp (dimension3): Hit-scoped

And these are being fed from an on-page script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    function getClientId() {
        try {
            var trackers = ga.getAll(); 
            var i, len;
            for (i= 0, len = trackers.length; i < len;  i += 1) {   
                if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1')  {
                    return trackers[i].get('clientId');
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            //do nothing
        }       
        return  'false';
    }

    function getSessionId() {
        return new  Date().getTime() + '.' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);
    }

    function getTimeStamp() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');

    var clientId = getClientId();
    var sessionId = getSessionId();
    var timeStamp = getTimeStamp();

    ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'dimension1' : clientId,
        'dimension2' : sessionId,
        'dimension3' : timeStamp
    });        
});
</script>
```

Now, the marketing team tells us that ClientId is not getting captured. They shared data where we had some 24,000 rows, out of which only two had valid client ids. By contrast, Session ID and Hit Timestamp are being captured perfectly.

When I do a quick check on the website (by assigning the code for getClientId() to another temporary function and calling it), I get the ClientId.

I'm really not sure what's causing this to be missed on the live website. Can someone point out something that might be awry?

Comment: What reason do you have for loading the analytics library on `$(document).ready`, rather than within <script> tags? Also, what error message do you see, if any, in the console when the page loads?

Comment: @nyuen Very good point! I think that's a bad idea. There are no error messages related to GA when the page loads. Your comment has given me a direction to work on. I'm going to load the JS directly in `<script>` tags and do the actual sending on `window.bind("load", ...` (because they have an older version of jQuery). Will report back soon!

Comment: Do you mean the sending of the pageview? You should probably not do that on `window.load` either because you want to be able to capture the visit ASAP, so even before the user has a chance to unload the page.

Comment: @nyuen Hmmm, okay. Will try that as well.

Comment: If you have only one GA on site i think it's easier to use shortcut version of get clientid: ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');

Comment: @nyuen It worked! Thank you so much. :-) Can I request you to add an answer below?

Comment: @JacekSzymański Thanks, but I'm not sure if there are more trackers set up. Kinda new to the project so will play safe. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider loading the GA library as recommended in the `<head>` section of your site rather than on `$(document).ready`. This is so that the analytics tracking has the soonest possibility to start tracking user engagements. In addition, if you load the analytics after DOM is ready or after the page has completely loaded, then there is the chance you miss some metrics if, for example, a user lands on your page, and then navigates away before the analytics library has a chance to capture their data.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But I have a question. I hear that JS is async in nature, which (to me) means that it won't wait for analytics.js to load. As such, I fear that the code that comes later will be executed before the file has fully loaded. What do you say to that?

Comment: You could include a `hitCallback` to your GA hits (event, pageview) such that the functions you've called will be executed immediately after the GA hit is sent. You can read more about that here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback